# Why X mod 2pow(256) should return a fixed-size output of 256 bits?

Tags: binary, modular-arithmetic

This is written on page 26 of "Princeton Bitcoin book".
I think that I understand why 2pow(256) return 256 bit - length value,but why a remainder of the division of any number to 2pow(256) returns value of fixed length of 256 bits?

Comment: 2 to the power of 256 is actually a 257 bit number. It's the smallest 257 bit number with a leading 1.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the correction! Still, how is that the remainder of the division of any number to 2pow(256) should return a value of fixed length?

Answer (score 3):

If you do mod with any number `n`, The possible outcome is from the range `0` to `n-1`.

Here you are doing mod with `2pow(256)` which is a `257` bit number as Most Significant bit as `1` and `256` `0`s.

The possible outcome is from the range `0` to `(2pow(n))-1` which can be represented using 256 bits as the maximum value `(2pow(n))-1` which is in binary form `256` continuous `1`s.

So output length or range will be fixed and it can be represented using n bits if you are doing mod with number `2pow(n)`.

Try to understand it with length 4.

so 2pow(4) is 16. In binary form `10000` which consists of `5` bits.

If you do any number mod `2pow(4`) answer will be from `0` to `15` which can be represented using `4` bits. 
Suppose if we start from `0`. `0` mod `2pow(4)` is `0` which can be represented with `4` bits.
So upto `15` it will give same output(`number` mod `2pow(4)`) as the input so it can be represented using `4` bits.

```
0%16=0        Binary:0000
1%16=0        Binary:0001
2%16=0        Binary:0010
.........................
.........................
15%16=0        Binary:1111
16%16=0        Binary:0000
17%16=1        Binary:0001
.........................
.........................
31%16=0        Binary:1111
32%16=0        Binary:0000
33%16=1        Binary:0001
.........................
```

This sequence keeps on going.

For the input `16` again it will give output `0`.(`16` mod `2(pow)4`). So this sequence keeps going upto `(2(pow)4)-1`. then again it will repeat.

Comment: Aha! So the only thing that the book author failed to mention (and I thought that I am missing something!) is that the remainder can be left-padded with 0-s to fit into 256-bit length. Thank you for clarification!